# Remove extra space between functions and labels, when subscripts are used

Tags: plotting, labeling

I want to plot a function for different values of my parameter, 'y_a', where `a` is a subscript. Here is my code:

```
f1[x_] := x/0.15 - 1/0.8
f2[x_] := x/0.25 - 1/0.8
f3[x_] := x/0.45 - 1/0.8

Plot[{f1[x], f2[x], f3[x]}, {x, 0, 0.9}, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", 
 AxesLabel -> {"x","f(x)"}, PLotLabels -> {"y_a=0.15","y_a=0.25","y_a=0.45"}]
```

When I execute my code, an extra space between the function and the labels is generated, if I use `ctrl+-` command to create a subscript. So, I would be grateful if you could tell me how I can remove this extra space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Plot[{f1[x], f2[x], f3[x]}, {x, 0, 0.9}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "f(x)"}, 
 PlotLabels ->  Placed[Pane[ToString[Subscript[y, a],StandardForm]<>" = " 
  <>ToString @ #]& /@ {0.15, 0.25, 0.45}, After]]
```

[image]

Comment: My question was uncleared. Please have a look at my improved question

Comment: @Yorgos, please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
Plot[{f1[x], f2[x], f3[x]}, {x, 0, 0.9}, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", 
AxesLabel -> {"x", "f(x)"}, 
PlotLabels -> {Row[{Subscript[y, a], "=", 0.15}, "\[ThinSpace]"], 
Row[{Subscript[y, a], "=", 0.25}, "\[ThinSpace]"], 
Row[{Subscript[y, a], "=", 0.45}, "\[ThinSpace]"]}]
```

[image]